# Rest API for disconnect/reconnect slave from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I know we can post the following to offline a slave on Jenkins

http://[jenkins_url]:8080/computer/[slave_name]/toggleOffline?offlineMessage=bye

but is there one for disconnecting and connecting slave?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but you might find this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/rZq1I7IsdnM) useful.

Answer (score 12):

I ended up had to guess the api, but at least I found it. For those who are interested, there are the api link to disconnect and reconnect a slave agent to Jenkins.

Disconnect:
http://[jenkins_url]:8080/computer/[slave_name]/doDisconnect?offlineMessage=bye

Reconnect:
http://[jenkins_url]:8080/computer/[slave_name]/launchSlaveAgent

Comment: the API area of jenkins documentation is terrible. The worst thing about guessing them is that feeling that we may be using undocumented API's that may then change.This might be why it is undocumented too...

Comment: I received a `Response Code: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: The 405 was due to a "GET". Changing to post it succeded.

Answer (score 1):

This used an `api token` for the user.

```
curl -X POST https://user:token@host/computer/node_name/launchSlaveAgent
```