# What is the programmatic way to disconnect a node in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, nodes, disconnect

I want to accomplish, through a script using the Jenkins API, the equivalent of manually clicking on the "Disconnect" link on the node management page in Jenkins. I want to add this code to a script I made using the Pipeline scripting plugin.

In other words, as a user with Jenkins admin privileges, do

```
Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Click on a node -> Click on "Disconnect"
```

As in:

[image: Mange Node Page]

I do not want to do the equivalent of "temporarily mark this node as offline".
That is not useful to me.

Answer (score 7):

The `hudson.model.Computer` class has a `disconnect(DisconnectReason)` method

Here are the [docs for this](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#disconnect-hudson.slaves.OfflineCause-)

In my case, I was able to acquire the `Computer` instance and disconnect by using `Jenkins.instance.getNode(...).getComputer().disconnect(...)`

Comment: That seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: For some reason, the command succeeded but still the agent did not disconnect. What could be the reason ?  Jenkins.instance.getNode("agent_name").getComputer().disconnect(hudson.slaves.OfflineCause.create(hudson.model.Messages._Hudson_NodeBeingRemoved()))

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything in the [pipeline-model-definition-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin) regarding node management.

So an alternative approach would be to call the disconnect action through the Jenkins API from the pipeline.

- The [Jenkins API for disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708292/6309) is:

  ```
  http://[jenkins_url]:8080/computer/[slave_name]/doDisconnect?offlineMessage=bye
  ```
- Making a [Jenkins API call from a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473396/6309) is done through the [JENKINS HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin):

  ```
  def response = httpRequest "http://..."
  ```

Comment: Hi Von, Thanks for your help. I tried the httpRequest and it gave me:        [Pipeline] httpRequest
HttpMode: GET
URL: http://myjenkins.mydomain.local:8080/computer/ci-xx-2/doDisconnect?offlineMessage=bye
Sending request to url: http://myjenkins.mydomain.local:8080/computer/ci-da-2/doDisconnect?offlineMessage=bye
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Fail: the returned code 405 is not in the accepted range: [[100‥399]]
Finished: FAILURE