# What is the programmatic way to disconnect an agent in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

Jenkins has a programmatic mechanism for taking nodes offline, is there an equivalent for Bamboo? Ideally I could trigger an offline disconnect after the agent finishes any currently executing jobs.

[What is the programmatic way to disconnect a node in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097002/what-is-the-programmatic-way-to-disconnect-a-node-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the Bamboo REST API.  Here is a [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.10.4/#d2e853) to the specific call `DELETE /agent/{agentId}`.