# Make Jenkins node offline if job passes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

Is there any script or plugin so that I can take Jenkins node offline automatically if the job passes.
Or if i explicitly give choice parameter to take node offline after current build.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned before an [API for disconnecting a node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098058/6309): see more at "[Monitor and Restart Offline Slaves](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitor+and+Restart+Offline+Slaves)".

That means you can add a post-build action, which would call this api though curl.