# How to automatically disconnect Jenkins Slave agent from Master controller server post build completion?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

We have a requirement to automatically disconnect Jenkins Slave agent from Master controller server once the build has been completed irrespective of its status. We are using windows agents in our case.

Anybody is having any idea, how to do that ?

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097002/what-is-the-programmatic-way-to-disconnect-a-node-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

In the slave configuration page, there is a field calles "availability".

Check "Take this slave on-line when in demand and off-line when idle" and it should disconnect after running the job.

Comment: If there are more jobs in queue on the remote agent the machine will not stay disconnected